# Order relations and group actions

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, order-theory, group-actions

Suppose I define a group action with group $G$ over some set $X$. The set is totally ordered in an arbitrary way $X = [x_1, \dots, x_N]$. Then, the group action defines permutations of the indices $[g(1), \dots, g(N)]$ for each element $g\in G$. Call the set of such permutations of the indices $S = \{[i_1, \dots, i_N]\mid \exists g \in G : \forall j : g \cdot x_j = x_{i_j}\}$.

For example, if $X$ contains 4 elements and $G = C_4$, I can choose an ordering of $X$ such that $S = \{[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,1,2,3]\}$.

Suppose that I choose to interpret the different permutations as valid orderings of the indices.

**Questions** : For a given group $G$ is there a way to define an order relation on $X$ for which the elements of $S$ are the only valid orderings? Are there properties that these order relations will respect?

For the above example, the order relation I would be looking for is a [cyclic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order) generated by the ternary relations $[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,1]$.

Comment: I don’t get the ending, why do the cycles suddenly have $3$ elements, and there are only $3$ of them?

Comment: Also, although you don’t say it, I assume you want $X$ finite. Is $G$ finite?

Comment: Every group action $G$ on $X$ is a homomorphism $G\to \Sigma_X,$ where $\Sigma_{X}$ is the set of bijections/permutations $X\to X.$ A total ordering of $X,$ if finite, gives a specific isomorphism $\Sigma_{X}\to \Sigma_N,$ where $N=|X|$ and $\Sigma_{N}=\Sigma_{\{1,2,\dots,N\}}$ is the symmetry group on $n$ elements.

Comment: In particular, if $G=\Sigma_{X}$ and the map $G\to \Sigma_X$ is the identity, then you get all possible orderings of the cycles.

Comment: OK corrected, there was a missing question mark. For the ending, I'm saying that cyclic order is defined by these ternary relations

Comment: Those aren’t relations, those are tuples. What exactly do you mean by “relations?”

Comment: I mean a 3-ary relation. According to the cited wikipedia article, they allow to define cyclic orders.

Comment: If you understood the logic of the question, but think that the notation or phrasing is not clear, feel free to make modification, I'm not extremely good with that

Comment: Given an action of $G$ on an ordered $X$ it **seems** you are defining: $$S=\{[i_1,i_2,\dots,i_N]\mid \exists g\in G: \forall j: g\cdot x_j=x_{i_j}\}$$  We can definitely define $S,$ and it is unique, given the action and the ordering of $X.$

Comment: Well, that article has, for each cycle, a set of $3$-tuples.

Comment: So for $[1,2,3,4],$ the ternary relation is $$\{[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4], [2,3,4],[2,3,1],[2,4,1],[3,4,1],[3,4,2],[3,1,2],[4,1,2],[4,1,3],[4,2,3]\}$$

Comment: Indeed, for your example $S,$ the ternary order is the same for each element. But that won’t be generally true. You can get literally any ternary order.

Comment: That's exactly the set $S$ I'm defining yes. For the ternary relations, the example is not crucial. Seems to me that those you enumerate can be derived from the three I listed from transitivity, etc. In any case, I welcome any concrete suggestion to improve clarity of the question.

Comment: In reality, for finite cyclic orders, you don’t need a ternary order, just a list of pairs of consecutive values. Then $[1,2,3,4]$ could be represented as $$\{[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,1]\}$$

Comment: OK! Any way to define the order relation works, the only important thing is that it strictly agrees with set $S$.

Comment: Well, you could be explicit that you mean those three ternary elements *generate* a single cyclic order ternary relation, not “relations” plural, and it is satisfied by all the elements of the elements of this particular  $S.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129890/discussion-between-undead-and-thomas-andrews).

Answer (score 1):

The only way for a single cyclic order relation to apply to all elements of $S$ is if $G$ acts cyclically on $X$ in a particular way.

That can be phrased as,

1. For some $g\in G,$ and $d\mid N,$ $g^d\cdot x=x$ for all $x\in X,$ and if $g^i\cdot x\neq x$ for any $x\in X$ and $0<i<d,$ and
2. For any $h\in G,$ there is an $i=0,1,\dots,d-1$ so that $h\cdot
       x=g^{i}\cdot x$ for all $x\in X.$

A more advanced way of saying this is if the image of $G$ in $\Sigma_X$ is cyclic of order $d$ and the orbits of the action are all size $d.$

Let $g\in G$ be a generator of the cyclic group in the image.

Let $X_1,\dots, X_{N/d}$ be the orbits.

Pick any $x_i\in X_i.$

Then we can pick the total order:

$$
\begin{align} 
[&x_{1},\dots,x_{N/d},\\
&g\cdot x_1,\dots,g\circ x_{N/d},\\
&g^2\cdot x_1,\dots,g^2\cdot x_{N/d},\\
&\vdots\\
&g^{d-1}\cdot x_1,\dots,g^{d-1}\cdot x_{N/d}]
\end{align} 
$$

Then every element of $S$ will have the same cyclic order as $[1,2,\dots,N].$

But it won’t be true that every tuple with that order will be in $S.$ There will only be $d$ elements of $S,$ and there are $N$ different tuples with the same cyclic order. So $S$ is only totally defined by a cyclic order if $d=N.$

---

If $G=C_2=\{e,g\}$ and $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with $$g\cdot a=d, g\cdot b=c, g\cdot c=b, g\cdot d =a,$$ then the orbits are $X_1=\{a,d\}$ and $X_2=\{b,c\}$ and we can pick $x_1=d,x_2=b$ and you get $$x_1=d<X
x_2=b<x_3=g\cdot d=a<x_4=g\cdot b=c$$ and  $$S=\{[1,2,3,4],[3,4,1,2]\}$$